# How to send a photo stored locally using telegraf API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm a beginner with this.

I'm trying to develop a Telegram bot using [Telegraf API](https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=sendphoto). I'm stuck when the user sends a certain command (in my case: `'/details <number>'`) and the bot has to reply with a specific photo stored locally inside the bot folder (based on the number that user types).

I managed to achieve it using telegram-bot-api but since the API are not that completed, I switched to Telegraf. I tried to understand the official Telegraf documentation but I'm not able to fully understand it.

Looking at the [official examples](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/docs/examples/example-bot.js) and copy it to a new project obviously worked.

I'm having trouble with Photos stored locally and even on understand how 'bot.command' works at this point.

this one works:
`bot.command('text', ({replyWithPhoto}) => replyWithPhoto(url: <url>));`
When the user types: '/text' he gots the photo back based on the URL.
I thought it was the same for the photo stored locally, but it's not..

```
var filePath = "./assets/monsters/"+monsterList[2].name+"/sample.png";
bot.command('text', ({replyWithPhoto}) => replyWithPhoto(filePath));
```

filepath I'm sure it's correct.

The code right now:

```
bot.on('text', function(ctx){
   var chat_id = ctx.from.id;
   var text = ctx.message.text;

   var index = 0;
   var commandDetails="";
   if (text/includes("/details ")){
      try{
       var split = text.split(' ');
       index = Number(split[1]);
       commandDetails = '/details'+index.toString();
      }catch(e){}
   }

   switch(text){

      case: 'bla bla bla';break;
      case ''+commandDetails:
            try{
               var filePath = './a.png';
               ///read below **
            }
   }
})
```

///read here **: here if i put bot.command(blabla); It's not working, maybe because it's like 'waiting' for another message input i guess... I tried even with the url: same result.

So, the first part of the code should be really bad but the concept is to have the switch case that works whenever the users type `'/details <number>'`. I have a list that will grow bigger and bigger so I tried to do it as clean as possible.

How can I send Photo with this system?
PS: Once i was using Telegram-bot-api, putting the function sendphoto function where it should be now it was working correctly.

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass `source` instead of `url`. There's an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/f199ab1c93008a86878c56cb837a78a1c980b57c/docs/examples/media-bot.js#L10).

```
ctx.replyWithPhoto({ source: '/cats/cat1.jpeg' });
```